# how to create specialization of method inherited from class template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base class template and a class deriving from an instantiation of it:

```
template<typename T>
class Bar
{
   template <T t>
   void Foo();
};

class Derived : public Bar<int> {};
```

How should one implement Derived::Foo<0>() for example?
when trying this out:

```
template<>
void Derived::Foo<0>() { /* impl.. */}
```

i get the following compile error:

```
template-id 'Foo<0>' for 'Derived::Foo()' does not match any template declaration.
```

Comment: Isn't this a rehashed version of your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74558694/817643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specialize it in the descendant; you can only add a signature that'll serve as an overload and delegate as necessary:

```
template<typename T>
class Bar
{
   template <T t>
   void Foo();
};

class Derived : public Bar<int> {
   using Base = Bar<int>;

   template <int t>
   void Foo()
   {
      if constexpr(t == 0) {
         /* impl... */
      } else {
         Base::Foo<t>();
      }
   }
};
```

Since the ADL / Koenig lookup of a class does not include template base class(es), I'd not expect any issues during overload resolution if you do it this way.